# Как дать значение по умолчанию в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть параметр znah_1. Мне нужно, чтобы он имел значения параметра 
по умолчанию.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Из вашего вопроса не вполне понятно, но если Вы имеете в виду значение параметра по умолчанию для функции, то.
**ES5, Способ 1:**
Честный способ. Параметр который не пришел, следовательно должен быть установлен по умолчанию имеет значение undefined.

```
function myFunc(znah_1){
    znah_1 = typeof znah_1 !== 'undefined' ? znah_1 : '666'; // 666 - my default value
}
```

**ES5, Способ 2:**
Самый распространенный способ. Пользуемся тем, что оператор или возвращает самый левый аргумент, который не приводится к false. Но надо понимать, что если вам надо как-то особенно отрабатывать входной параметр приводящийся к false, но не undefined (false, null, '', 0), то так делать нельзя.

```
function myFunc(znah_1){
    znah_1 = znah_1 || 666; // 666 - my default value
}
```

**ES2015:**
Просто и интуитивно.

```
function myFunc(znah_1 = 666){ // 666 - my default value
}
```